# PostgreSQL: Check if row exists or another row has a specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have the following tables:
[image]

When a new ComputerComponents is created, the database should check and only allow the insertion IF one is true:

- ComputerComponent has a component which is a ComponentType with name = 'GPU'

OR

- ComputerComponent has a component which is a ComponentType with name = 'CPU' AND the CPU has a Attribute with name = 'Onboard-GPU' and the ComponentAttribute value = TRUE

How do i do this?

Comment: If this is for an application you are writing, I would advise against putting this logic in your data layer; put it in your controller layer -- it'll make for more maintainable code in the future.

Comment: It is. But i am using this project to learn SQL - and thus i need to know how to implement this procedure / trigger on the data layer for training purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an insert [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/trigger-definition.html) on the effected table.

Comment: I am new to SQL - i've read alot about Triggers - but i can't figure out how to implement the specific trigger that i need here.

Comment: Your trigger would pass through the values as provided if they meet the conditions you outline, `NULL` otherwise. You should be able to pull this off with an `if` statement.

Comment: I get your idea - but i still don't know how to exactly implement it. Could you show me an example?

Comment: Not getting specific to your case, a set of examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Comment: On which of the tables? Can a computer be created before adding components, or can you add components to a not yet existing computer?

Comment: @Politank-Z i've already read alot of examples, but finding it very hard to transfer it to mine..

Comment: @jarlh A computer can be created first, then components are added

Comment: I have a hard time finishing this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7647549/Capture123123.PNG

Comment: Sorry for the delay, dropbox is blocked at my office. I urge you to read the documentation I linked to - your return type is wrong. You need to look at the `NEW` variable for accessing the data which the trigger routine is examining. You need to declare your trigger function before you declare the trigger. I know these things can be frustrating when you get started, but you need to take the time to learn the right ways. We aren't here to do it for you,

Comment: @CasperTL, since a computer can be created before any items are added, it's a bit tricky to use a trigger to verify items. Perhaps you can have an update trigger on the computer table, where you switch the column "status" to 'complete' when all items have been added.

Comment: @jarlh That is a great idea, i will do that. However, could you help me with the trigger? I guess you have all the info you need with the tables above :)

Comment: @CasperTL. Nope, I don't know postgresql's triggers. (Besides I'd have to charge you for that.)